# Windows VM in Gnome-Boxes won't grab mouse or respect mouse movement

Tags: virtual-machine, gnome

I have installed a copy of Windows 7 as a guest in a Gnome Boxes VM. During install, it behaved normally, as do various Linux distros I have also set up as guests. Based on rules I can't fathom, all of these do one of two things with respect to the mouse - they will either:

- Grab the mouse when I click in the guest OS, so that it can't escape the VM window, and the text at the top changes from "Press and release (left) Ctrl+Alt to ungrab keyboard" to "... to ungrab" ; or
- Allow the mouse to leave, but have the guest OS cursor follow mouse movements while in the VM window

The Windows 7 guest does neither. I move the mouse inside the VM window, the host cursor vanishes, but the Windows cursor stays still and I can navigate by keyboard only. Interestingly, the same VM loaded through virt-manager (by pointing it at the appropriate drive image in `~/.local/share/gnome-boxes`) behaves the same way, but a newly-created one in virt-manager using the same Windows install media appears to work properly. Is there a way to convince Gnome Boxes to do.. well, *something* sensible?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue. Boxes was grabbing the mouse, but the cursor of the guest Win7 would not move. At the same time, however, keyboard was fully responsive.

I managed to fix it using the [**Spice Windows Guest Tools**](https://www.spice-space.org/download.html#windows-binaries).

---

I also found [bug ticket](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=676225) that I thought it *might* be relevant, but I couldn't test. The ticket is a bit old, and it refers to a WinXP guest, but the problem seems to be the same. Apparently the author solved it by installing `virt-manager` and setting up a USB mouse from there. Again, couldn't test myself it is relevant.

Comment: Thank you! I will give it a try as I was having the same problem!

Comment: **Update:** I have been working 8 hours straight without finding any issue again! Thank you so much for your help! :D

Comment: This fixed a similar issue where clicking would move the mouse. Thank you so much!